# How to make BizTalk to trust self-signed certificate negotiated through Send Port?

Tags: security, ssl, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have `Send Port` with `Dynamic Solicit-Response` type.

Everything needed for the Send Port is dynamically configured inside the Orchestration and `Security Mode` is set to `Transport`.

**Encryption Certificate** for the Send Port is not configured. (I guess IIS already handling it?)

**Decryption Certificates** for Host and IsolatedHost instances are also not configured. (*this is the part where i believe that BizTalk will trust certificates depending on current certificates in Trusted Root Certification Authorities*)

Yes, the `Send Port` will make request on endpoint that uses self-signed certificate.

What I tried:

- I tried importing the self-signed certificate in **Trusted Root Certification Authorities**, **Other People** under **Local Machine** and **Current User** (User that owns the BizTalk host)
- I tried manually setting up the Encryption certificate to use the self-signed certificate

Nothing works...

Comment: Is the self-signed certificate you are trying to use the one for the target server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable WCF self signed certificate validation in BizTalk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19550211/disable-wcf-self-signed-certificate-validation-in-biztalk)

Answer (score 0):

If the security mode is Transport, then the certificate that is needs will be one which contains the public key and that matches the target server.   If this is a self-signed certificate then it needs to be in the Trusted Root Certification Authorities, Certificates for the BizTalk Host User.

Comment: Well its kinda what i did...
That self signed certificate with private key and public key, created from IIS's Create Self Signed Certificate button is used for SSL communication. I put that certificate (only public key) on server where is the BizTalk Application, i installed it into Trusted Root Authorities Store for Local Machine and BizTalk Host User. 
However i obtained CA and certificate from Active Directory server, and now it works...

Comment: @JovanMeshkov Did you create the self signed certificate on the IIS on the BizTalk server, or the target server where the send port sends too?  The name in the certificate needs to match the target server.

Comment: Well I guess that is the actual problem. IIS -> Create Self-Signed Certificate creates certificate that is bound to IIS's host server with no option to change it. So i end up with IssuedBy: 'MyServerName' and IssuedTo: 'MyServerName'. I was hoping that even it is issued to 'MyServerName' if i place it in Trusted Root Authorities store, BizTalk server will still validate it...